# Prohibit a class from exposing a method

Tags: c#, class, oop, interface

Is there any way to prohibit a class from exposing a certain method or property? This is somewhat like a counter concept to interfaces.

Example:

```
class A : [Somehow prevent to expose method X]
{

}

class B : A 
{
   public void X() // --> Should cause compile error
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess there is something like private,sealed !!

Comment: @ubaid gadha: `private` can't be inheritedm so `sealed` is redundant

Comment: Please show some example code that illustrates your question, as it's unclear what you're asking. Do you mean you want to mark a class like _"this class will never expose the `string Foo()` method and it must be a compile time error if it does"_? Also explain why you'd want such a thing.

Comment: this is the concept which you learn on the first day in oops.

Comment: You missed the "why" part of my comment. No, you can't easily do this. You could perhaps use some Aspect Oriented framework that checks your code pre or post compile.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to expose a method or property, why not simply use the `private` access modifier for that method or property?

Comment: and remove it from interface

Answer (score 1):

The question is a *vague* one, sounds as *explicit interface implementatio*n:

```
  public interface IMyIntf {
    void SomeMethod();
  }

  public class MyClass: IMyIntf {
    ...
    // explicit interface implementation: works as "private"
    // unless cast to the interface
    void IMyIntf.SomeMethod() {
      ...
    }
  }

  ...

  MyClass inst = new MyClass();

  inst.SomeMethod(); // <- compile time error: SomeMethod() is not exposed

  // Only when cast the inst to the interface one can call the method:
  ((IMyIntf) inst).SomeMethod();
```